# How to display "\,,/" as string

Tags: java, android, string

I want to display  `\ ,,/` as  a string in Java but i am getting Invalid escape sequence.

Tried all possible ways

```
   String Metal= "'\'"+",,/";

   Toast a= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Metal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   a.show();

   String Metal= "\"+",,/";
```

Getting the out put as `",,/`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just escape the `\`:

```
String Metal = "\\,,/";
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work: `String Metal= "'\\'"+",,/";`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
String Metal= "\\ ,,/ ";
```

You have to escape `\` that's why `\\` here.